# BGP influence outbound traffic based on prefix

Tags: cisco, routing, bgp, network

I have two router `core1` and `core2` connected with ISP router border1 and border2 using `eBGP` peer and i have 5 public subnect (/24). My ISP sending me default route instead of full BGP table.

Question: I have 5 public IP subnets (prefix) and now i want 3 prefix traffic go out from `core1` and remaining 2 subnet traffic go out from `core2` and bore core1/2 connected over iBGP so how do i influance outgoing traffic using local-pref?  (we can use AS prepend to inflaunce inbound traffic)

How do i create prefix-list to make my first 3 subnet use core1 ?

[image]

Comment: "we can use AS prepend to inflaunce inbound traffic" In my experience AS prepend doesn't work this well. Many providers filter out routes that have more than 3 times the same AS. If your two /24 belongs to the same /23 the best way is to announce the /24 on the link you want the traffic to come through and the /23 on the other link.

Comment: Please note that your use of the terminology "border" as in border router in the above diagram is incorrect and may lead to confusion.  Your core-1 and core-2 routers are also your ASBRs -- your border routers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your post states your ISPs send you default routes only.  Therefore, you'll need to configure static routes toward the desired transit provider to direct traffic for the 5 routes of interest to ISP A or B.

Assume `192.0.2.0/24` is a prefix you want to route to the Internet via ISP A which has next-hop address `203.0.113.1`:

```
route-map redist-to-bgp permit 100
  match tag 1
route-map redist-to-bgp deny 9999
!
router bgp 64496
  redistribute static route-map redist-to-bgp
!
ip route 192.0.2.0 255.255.255.0 203.0.113.1 tag 1
```

Comment: I have only single ISP and they have two border1 and border2 router for residency and reason i need to split my subnet out for both router to utilize bandwidth, so local-pref won't work in my scenario right?

Comment: You don't even need to use local-preference.  You'll only have one route -- a static route via the link you have selected.  The `redistribute` command will import that route into BGP.  Presumably, you have an iBGP session between your `core1` and `core2` routers and the `192.0.2.0/24 -> 203.0.113.1` route will be propagated by iBGP to the other core router.  You're not learning this /24 route from both ISP circuits via eBGP -- you are configuring it statically.  There's only the one route so you don't have to local-pref it up.

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting default from both circuits and you want traffic *from* certain subnets to use a specific circuit to send traffic out?
Assuming the traffic hits the right border it will use the circuit connected to it because eBGP trumps ibgp for the same prefix. This means your routing decision is at the cores not the borders so make sure the link from core 1 to border 1 is lower cost than core 1 to border 2 and vice versa - this will mean anything connected to core 1 will go via border 1 and circuit 1 and anything connected to core 2 will go via border 2 and circuit 2. You can probably do this with your IGP but would need to see more of your config to advise.